# scrollViewDidEndDecelerating method won't called under certain condition

Tags: ios

if I keep scrolling the scrollview very fast,it seems that this delegate method won't be called,is there a way to fix this? thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you want to know the deceleration has ended when it's started accelerating again? Is it not being called when you stop scrolling?